# Hive Query that returns distinct value that each User has

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a mysql table-

```
User    Value
A   1
A   12
A   3
B   4
B   3
B   1
C   1
C   1
C   8
D   34
D   1
E   1
F   1
G   56
G   1
H   1
H   3
C   3
F   3
E   3
G   3
```

I need to run a query which returns 2nd distinct value that each user has.
Means if any 2 values are accessed by each user , then based on the occurrence, pick the 2nd distinct value.

> So as above 1 & 3 is being accessed by each User. Occurrence of 1 is
>   more than 3 , so 2nd distinct will be 3

So I thought first I will get all distinct user.

```
create table temp AS Select distinct user from table;
```

Then I will have an outer query-

```
Select value from table where value in (...)
```

In programmatically way , I can iterate through each of the value user contains like Map but in Hive query I just couldn't write that.

Comment: what you mean by second distinct value?
give an example

Comment: No where does `D` access `3` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the second most frequented value from your list that spans all users.  There isn't one of these values in the table which I expect is a typo in the data.  In real data you will likely have muliple ties that you need to figure out how to handle.

```
Select value as second_distinct from
 (select value, rank() over (order by occurrences desc) as rank
 from
   (SELECT value, unique_users, max(count_users) as count_users, count(value) as occurrences
     from
        (select value, size(collect_set(user) over (partition by value)) 
         as count_users from my_table
        ) t
     left outer join
        (select count(distinct user) as unique_users from my_table
        ) t2 on (1=1)
        where unique_users=count_users
        group by value, unique_users
    ) t3
 ) t4
where rank = 2;
```

This works.  It returns NULL because there is only value that visited every user (value of 1).  Value 3 is not a solution because not every user has seen that value in your data.  I expect you intended that three should be returned but again it doesn't span all the users (user D did not see value 3).

Comment: `length(collect_set(user))` makes zero sense.  `length` is a string function

Comment: Should be size, returns the number of elements invan array

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how @invoketheshell's answer was marked correct; it doesn't run and it needs 6 MR jobs.  This will get you there in 4 and is less code.

**Query**:

```
select value
from (
  select value, value_count, rank() over (order by value_count desc) rank
  from (
    select value, count(value) value_count
    from (
      select value, num_users, max(num_users) over () max_users
      from (
        select value
          , size(collect_set(user) over (partition by value)) num_users
        from db.table ) x ) y
    where num_users = max_users
    group by value ) z ) f
where rank = 2
```

**Output**:

```
3
```

**EDIT**:  Let me clarify my solution as there seems to be some confusion.  The OP's example says

> "So as above 1 & 3 is being accessed by each User ... "

As my comment below the question suggests, in the example given, user `D` never accesses value `3`.  I made the assumption that this was a typo and added this to the dataset and then added another `1` as well to make there be more `1`'s than `3`'s.  So my code correctly returns `3`, which was the desired output.  If you run this script on the *actual* dataset it will also produce the correct output which is nothing because there isn't a "2nd Distinct".  The only time it *could* produce an incorrect value, is if there was *no one specific number* that was accessed by all users, which illustrates the point I was trying to make to @invoketheshell: if there is no single number that every user has accessed, ***running a query with 6 map-reduce jobs is an absurd way to find that out.***  Since we are using `Hive` I believe it would be fair to assume that if this problem were a "real-world" problem, it would most likely be executed on at least 100's of TBs of data (probably more).  I the interest of preserving time and resources, it would behoove an individual to at least check that one number had been accessed by all users before running a massive query whose analysis hinges on that assumption being true.

Comment: it runs with little bit of modification , but this solution is using sub sub query , so will try and test this one

Comment: This query does not ensure the condition in your question: values are accessed by each user.

Comment: It operates under the assumption that at lest *one* user has seen every number, which if this wasn't the case, there wouldn't be much point to executing the query in the first place.

Comment: I said that backwards, at least *one* number has been seen by every user